# relocation error using sudo apt

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

my system arch is **amd64**, i installed **i386** as foreign arch and ran `sudo apt dist-upgrade` but after it finished, i keep getting this error while using apt:

```
apt-get: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0: symbol ZN3URIcvNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEB5cxx11Ev version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
```

even when i use aptitude:

```
aptitude: relocation error: aptitude: symbol ZN3URIcvNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEB5cxx11Ev version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
```

any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [bug #911090](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=911090). To work around it, you need to ensure that the `apt` and `libapt-pkg5.0` packages are kept in sync; you might need to download them manually [starting with the links at the top of this page](https://packages.debian.org/source/testing/apt). I’m not sure there’s a fix for `aptitude` yet.

Comment: thanks, i downloaded [this file](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/apt/download) but still don't know how to manualy install it, could you help?

Comment: `dpkg -i apt_1.7.0_amd64.deb` as root.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is now 2021, I just ran into something so similar, I post what I found on my Ubuntu 18.04 (evidently formerly Ubuntu 16.04) system. Looks like a user had installed a what looked like another version of Ubuntu in /usr/local/ and the 'apt-get' binary was trying to use the wrong libapt-private.so.0.0. I cleaned out /usr/local/ and apt-get started working again. Hopefully this will save someone time in the future:

```
# apt-get update
apt-get: relocation error: apt-get: symbol _Z15InstallPackagesR9CacheFilebbbRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK11CommandLine version APTPRIVATE_0.0 not defined in file libapt-private.so.0.0 with link time reference
# 
# locate libapt-private.so.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0.0
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0.0
# 
# ls -l /usr/local
total 104
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 65536 Jul  7 19:30 bin
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Jul  7 14:35 DELETEME
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 24  2018 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 24  2018 games
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 24  2018 include
drwxr-xr-x 153 root root  4096 Sep 22  2020 lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     9 Sep 17  2018 man -> share/man
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jun  6  2007 opteronkiller
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep 17  2018 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Oct 20  2020 share
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 24  2018 src
# 
# 
# mv /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib-foo
# ls -l /usr/local
total 104
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 65536 Jul  7 19:30 bin
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Jul  7 14:35 DELETEME
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 24  2018 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 24  2018 games
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 24  2018 include
drwxr-xr-x 153 root root  4096 Sep 22  2020 lib-foo
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     9 Sep 17  2018 man -> share/man
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jun  6  2007 opteronkiller
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep 17  2018 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 Oct 20  2020 share
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 24  2018 src
# 
# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                           
Ign:3 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease                           
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                             
Hit:5 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Release       
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                           
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                     
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
#
```

So, looks like `apt-get` had not been working since Sept 20 when a user running as root installed the `/usr/local/lib`. This has restored `apt-get` functionality which the system needs...not sure what it broke for the user's applications. That's a story for another day.

Comment: I think most people would just do a fresh install - just so they would know its right!